# Recursive function based on While loop

Tags: r, function, loops, recursion, while-loop

Now I have my BOM data frame as follow with the approach of a data structure:

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(product_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2"), item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", 
"i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16", 
"i17", "i18"), sup_item_id = c("i6", "i6", "i6", "i6", "i8", 
"i8", "i9", "i9", NA, "i15", "i15", "i15", "i15", "i17", "i17", 
"i18", "i18", NA), quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1), price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
2, 5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0), itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

To define the item levels (from top to bottom) Here is my while loop:

```
   df2 <- df2 %>%
    arrange(product_id, item_id) %>%
    mutate(production_level = ifelse(is.na(sup_item_id), 0, 1))
idx <- which(df2$production_level == 1)
changed <- TRUE
while (changed) {
    changed <- FALSE
    for (i in idx) {
        descendants <- which(df2$sup_item_id == df2$item_id[i])
        if (length(descendants) > 0) {
            new_levels <- df2$production_level[i] + 1
            if (any(df2$production_level[descendants] < new_levels)) {
                df2$production_level[descendants] <- new_levels
                changed <- TRUE
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I dont want to use data tree to solve this. Can anyone help me translate my code to a recursive function?

Comment: We can also ignore using indices by applying this: df2 <- df2 %>%
  arrange(product_id, item_id) %>%
  mutate(production_level = ifelse(is.na(sup_item_id), 0, 1))

changed <- TRUE
while (changed) {
  changed <- FALSE
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(df2))) {
    descendants <- which(df2$sup_item_id == df2$item_id[i])
    if (length(descendants) > 0) {
      new_levels <- df2$production_level[i] + 1
      if (any(df2$production_level[descendants] < new_levels)) {
        df2$production_level[descendants] <- new_levels
        changed <- TRUE
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Below is a rather straightforward translation (without changing the `for` loop) of your `while` loop into a recursive function:

```r
library(dplyr)

change_df <- function(df, changed = TRUE, idx = which(df$production_level == 1)) {
  
  for (i in idx) {
    descendants <- which(df$sup_item_id == df$item_id[i])
    
    if (length(descendants) > 0) {
      new_levels <- df$production_level[i] + 1
      
      if (any(df$production_level[descendants] < new_levels)) {
        df$production_level[descendants] <- new_levels
        df <- change_df(df, idx = idx)
      }
      
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

 df2 %>%
  arrange(product_id, item_id) %>%
  mutate(production_level = ifelse(is.na(sup_item_id), 0, 1)) %>% 
  change_df(df2)

#>    product_id item_id sup_item_id quantity price itemtype production_level
#> 1          P1      i1          i6        2     2        A                3
#> 2          P1      i2          i6        2     5        A                3
#> 3          P1      i3          i6        5     3        A                3
#> 4          P1      i4          i6        1     7        A                3
#> 5          P1      i5          i8        1    10        A                2
#> 6          P1      i6          i8        2     0        B                2
#> 7          P1      i7          i9        4     4        A                1
#> 8          P1      i8          i9        1     0        B                1
#> 9          P1      i9        <NA>        1     0        C                0
#> 10         P2     i10         i15        2     2        A                3
#> 11         P2     i11         i15        2     5        A                3
#> 12         P2     i12         i15        5     3        A                3
#> 13         P2     i13         i15        1     7        A                3
#> 14         P2     i14         i17        1    20        A                2
#> 15         P2     i15         i17        2     0        B                2
#> 16         P2     i16         i18        4     2        A                1
#> 17         P2     i17         i18        1     0        B                1
#> 18         P2     i18        <NA>        1     0        C                0
```

Data from OP

```r
df2 <- structure(list(product_id = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
                              "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
                              "P2"), item_id = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "i6", "i7", 
                                                 "i8", "i9", "i10", "i11", "i12", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i16", 
                                                 "i17", "i18"), sup_item_id = c("i6", "i6", "i6", "i6", "i8", 
                                                                                "i8", "i9", "i9", NA, "i15", "i15", "i15", "i15", "i17", "i17", 
                                                                                "i18", "i18", NA), quantity = c(2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                                2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1), price = c(2, 5, 3, 7, 10, 0, 4, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                   2, 5, 3, 7, 20, 0, 2, 0, 0), itemtype = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>